Is the localization of a zero-dimensional ring a quotient?
If $R$ is any commutative zero-dimensional ring and $m$ is a maximal ideal, then is $R_m$ always naturally a quotient of $R$? In other words, is the natural map $R\to R_m$ always surjective? I was able to prove that this is true when $R$ is either Noetherian or reduced, but I am still unsure about the non-Noetherian non-reduced case. Does anyone know a proof or counterexample?
More generally, if $W$ is a multiplicative subset of $R$, I am curious whether the natural map $R\to W^{-1}R$ is surjective when $R$ is zero-dimensional.

If $R$ is zero-dimensional and reduced then every localization is surjective because $R$ is von Neumann regular (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_regular_ring). I don't know what happens in the non-reduced case.

@QiaochuYuan Yea, I worked out the reduced case that way. Still wondering about the general case though.

I will you give you three versions of an affirmative answer.
Answer 1: If $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ has a single point, then for any multiplicative set $S$, one of two things happens.  Either (1) the multiplicative set $S$ has non-empty intersection with the prime ideal of $A$, in which case $\operatorname{Spec}(S^{-1}A) = \emptyset$, i.e. $S^{-1}A = 0$; or (2) the multiplicative set $S$ is disjoint from the prime ideal of $A$, in which case $S$ consists of units of $A$ and $S^{-1}A = A$.  In either case it is clear that $A \rightarrow S^{-1}A$ is surjective.  Since a morphism $A \rightarrow B$ is surjective iff $A_\mathfrak{p} \rightarrow B_\mathfrak{p}$ is surjective for every prime $\mathfrak{p}$ of $A$, this shows that any localization of a $0$-dimensional ring is surjective.
Answer 2: In case you prefer a more concrete proof without localization:  recall that in a zero-dimensional ring $A$, every element $a \in A$ can be written in the form $a = eu + n$ where $n$ is nilpotent, $e$ is idempotent, and $u$ is a unit.  (This is clear if you understand the structure of reduced $0$-dimensional rings and know that units and idempotents lift modulo nil ideals).  First, note that $(1 - e)a = n(1-e)$, and therefore $a^ke = a^k$ for large $k$.  This implies that the image of $e$ in $A_a$ is the identity.  Second, if we take $b$ to be an element of the form $(eu - n)(eu^2 + n^2)(eu^4 + n^4) \cdots (eu^{2^m} + n^{2^m})$ for large enough $m$, then $ab = e u^N$ for some $N$.
Combining these two observations, we find that the image of $b (u^{-1})^N$ in $A_a$ is $1/a$.  This shows that $A \rightarrow A_a$ is surjective, and the case for arbitrary localizations follows immediately from the observation that any localization is a colimit of principal localizations.
Answer 3: Maybe you would be more interested more generally in the behavior of epimorphisms over $0$-dimensional rings.  The preceding result on localizations could be seen as a special case of the following more general result on flat epimorphisms:  If $A$ is a zero-dimensional ring and $f: A \rightarrow B$ is a flat epimorphism, then $f$ is a surjective.  Again, it suffices to check this locally, so we may assume that $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ consists of a single point.
If $B$ is zero then we are done.  Else, $\operatorname{Spec}(B) \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is surjective, so that $f$ is a faithfully flat epimorphism.  See Stacks [00HQ]. But faithfully flat epimorphisms are isomorphisms.  See Stacks [04VU].
Finally, we can also easily show that every finite type epimorphism from a zero-dimensional ring is surjective.  If $A \rightarrow B$ is a finite type epimorphism and $A$ is $0$-dimensional, then, letting $N$ be the nilradical of $A$, we have that $A/N \rightarrow B/NB$ is a flat epimorphism (because $A/N$ is absolutely flat) and therefore surjective.  Since $A \rightarrow B$ is an integral ring map modulo nilpotent elements, $A \rightarrow B$ is itself integral.  Thus $A \rightarrow B$ is finite type and integral by assumption, so $B$ is finitely generated as an $A$-module.  Since $A \rightarrow B$ is a finite epimorphism, it is a surjection.  See Stacks [04VT].

Beautiful! This is exactly what I was looking for. The key fact I was forgetting is that being surjective is a local property of module maps. If I had remembered that, I may have been able to work out Answer 1 at least. The other answers are very insightful too!

The only thing I’ll note is I think in your Answer 2, $b$ is supposed to be $(eu - n)(eu^2 + n^2)(eu^4 + n^4) \cdots (eu^{2^m} + n^{2^m})$ i.e. the first term in the product should have minus, and the rest should have plus. Thanks again!

@anon yes you are right about those darned signs! Fixed.

@anon btw, I hope it is clear from these answers that the property of localizations being surjective characterizes rings of krull dimension zero. And most interestingly, as comes out in answer 2, every element $a$ has a pointwise inverse $x_a$ such that $a^{n+1}x_a = a^n$ for some $n$.

Yes that does make sense. Thank you for the insight!

Here is an argument when $R_m$ is of finite length, not just zero dimensional.
In this case, we may assume $m^nR_m=0$ for all large $n$. Let $x\in R_m$ which is not in the image of $R$. Let $s\in R-m$ such that $sx$ is in the image. Since $s\not\in m$, one can find $a\in R, y\in m^n$ such that $as+y=1$. So $x=asx+xy$. But, $xy=0$ and $asx$ is in the image and, thus so is $x$, a contradiction.

How can you assume that $R_m$ has finite length? Consider for example $k[x_1,x_2,…]/(x_n^n: n\in\mathbb{Z}_+)$.

@Anon I did not say $R_m$ has finite length. But assuming that you get surjectivity.

I see. When you said “when $R_m$ is of finite length, not just zero-dimensional” I had taken that to mean you thought all zero-dimensional local rings have finite length. But I see now you meant when it is finite length in addition to being zero-dimensional.
